# Maximum likelihood estimate for intensity in observed Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, maximum-likelihood

Let $(X_t)_{0 \leq t \leq 1}$ be a Poisson process with intensity parameter $\lambda > 0$. The process is observed in $k$ time points $0 \leq t_1 < \cdots < t_k \leq 1$. Determine the MLE for $\lambda$.

I understand the task in the exercise that there exist values $x_1, \dots, x_k$ such that that $N_{t_i} = x_i$ is observed and thus using the fact that $$P(X_{t_i} = x_i) = \frac{(\lambda t_i)^{x_i}}{x_i!}e^{-\lambda t_i}$$ it follows that:
$$L(\lambda;x_1,\dots,x_k) = \prod_{i = 1}^k \frac{(\lambda t_i)^{x_i}}{x_i!}e^{-\lambda t_i}$$

After applying the logarithm and deriving the function, I get as MLE for $
\lambda$: $\hat{\lambda} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^k t_i}$

Is that correct? I have a feeling that I misunderstood the assignment itself.

Comment: Actually, what you need is rather $$P(N_{t_1}=x_1,\ldots,N_{t_k}=x_k)$$ which is not the product $L(\lambda;x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ that you wrote.

Comment: @Did Alright, in order to calculate this probabilty I want to use the independancy of the increments of the Poisson process, thus: $$P(N_{t_1}=x_1,\ldots,N_{t_k}=x_k) = P(N_{t_k}-N_{t_{k-1}}=x_k-x_{k-1},\dots,N_2-N_1=x_2-x_1,N_1=x_1) = \prod_{i=2}^k P(N_{t_i}-N_{t_{i-1}} = x_i-x_{i-1}) \cdot P(N_1=x_1)= \lambda^{x_k}\cdot C\cdot e^{-\lambda x_k}$$ By applying logarithm and deriving the function I get as MLE: $\lambda = \dfrac{x_k}{t_k}$. This result looks a lot more plausible, is it correct?